# Viewing Bookmarks in Adobe Reader 9

Tags: bookmarks, adobe-reader

Why is there no way to show the bookmark panel in Adobe Reader 9?

Looked thru all the menus/properties/preferences.

There is no option to select Bookmarks under

**View >> Navigation panels >> (nothing for bookmarks here)**

Using Winnovative pdfConverter and trying to convert html code into reports.
Does adobe reader require there to be Bookmarks in the document for the panel to be an option?
Or is this seem feature I need to pay for from adobe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes unfortunately there isn't any option of adding bookmarks in Adobe Reader but there's a way around this. All you have to do is check the first option in Edit -> Preferences -> Documents.

Here's a complete article on how to do just that:
http://www.programmerfish.com/how-to-add-bookmark-in-pdf-adobe-acrobat-reader/

Comment: The OP asks about **showing bookmarks**, not **adding bookmarks**.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing an answer related to Adobe Reader X (I do not have Adobe Reader 9 to test it). It might be relevant.

There are two options for showing the Bookmarks panel:

1. Right click on the leftmost sidebar.
   You should see the bookmark icon and activate it. If it's not showing,  then there are no bookmarks in the document.
   I just checked it with two pdfs, one with bookmarks and one without them.
2. *View* -> *Show/Hide* -> *Navigation panes*. Again, you should see the bookmark icon and activate it.

Item 1 taken from [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/960294?start=0&tstart=0).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to ADD bookmarks in AR9. Obviously AR9 is only of interest under Linux. HOWEVER you can display bookmarks if they are already in the document e.g. TOC. They show up under View-> Navigation Panels

In my case dealing with a long document that did not have bookmarks, I simply moved it to a PC with Acrobat on it added the bookmarks (chapters) and they show up perfectly in AR9.

Answer (score 0):

I know you wanted to know how to show the bookmark panel in Adobe Reader 9; however, I am going start here (the answer to your question is at the end of this explanation): To add a bookmark in Adobe Reader 9.0, open the pdf, go to the desired page, right-click anywhere on the page, select Add Bookmark (or press Ctrl+B). You can set a zoom level for the page and it will also be saved with the bookmark. You should then name the bookmark by clicking the bookmark button in the Navigation Panel on the right side of the document. Note: Once you click on Add Bookmark, the Navigation Panel will open on the right side of the document. You can then rename the new bookmark (it will be named Untitled) along with other options. After renaming, you can click on the arrow at top right of the Navigation Panel to close the bookmark section of the panel. You can hide the Navigation Panel Buttons; however, if left open, you can choose a bookmark by clicking on the Bookmarks button (2nd button from top). If you do choose to hide the Navigation Panel, to reopen it you will have to go to the View tab, Navigation Panels, and choose Show Navigation Pane (or press F4 while in the document).